# PostgreSQL seems to create inefficient plans in simple conditional joins

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-9.3, execution-plan, performance, postgresql-performance

Consider these two queries:

```
SELECT
    t1.id, *
FROM
    t1
INNER JOIN
    t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    where t1.id > -9223372036513411363;
```

And:

```
SELECT
    t1.id, *
FROM
    t1
INNER JOIN
    t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
    where t1.id > -9223372036513411363 and t2.id > -9223372036513411363;
```

**Note:** The `-9223372036513411363` is not the minimum value in the tables and the condition reduces the result (from the total number of rows, 350 million) to 17 million.

Personally, I expect PostgreSQL to come up with the same plan for both queries, because having `t1.id = t2.id` automatically implies the second condition. But unfortunately, PostgreSQL is creating two different plans with the plan for the second one being much better:

- First query: http://explain.depesz.com/s/uauk
- Second query: link: http://explain.depesz.com/s/uQd
- EXPLAIN ANALYZE for the second query: http://explain.depesz.com/s/Snkx
  (Second query finishes in 215 seconds, while the first one didn't finish after 1000 seconds until I terminated it).

I would highly prefer the first query, since I want to create a view from the join and put the where condition on queries on the view, where I see a single id column (I join using `USING` so a single id column is visible in view). Also, I will join more than two tables and I would prefer not to add such condition for each join.

Is there any reason for this behavior? Or is it a bug? Are there any workarounds?

- Replacing `ON t1.id = t2.id` with `USING (id)` makes no difference in both queries.
- This is PostgreSQL 9.3
- The actual number of returned rows is 17,658,189
- Analyze has been run on the tables. However, statistics related settings of PostgreSQL are its default values.
- Observation: Explain for query 1 has a good estimate for the final result, but uses a poor plan for querying t2. For 2nd query, estimates of the number of rows from t1 & t2 are good, but estimate for the final merge is about half the number of actual rows.
- The `id` column is primary key in both tables. Tables have around 350,000,000 rows. t1 is around 20GiB & t2 is 14GiB.
- Replacing `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` produces similar results
- Selecting less rows (by increasing the minimum ID value in where condition) doesn't make any differences, until the number of rows become too low in which case it uses a totally different plan.

#### What I'm trying to achieve

I have a DB with a lot of rows, and new data is being inserted to it continuously. We want to generate different reports for this data, which includes different kinds of queries like: searching for different data, sorting by each column, aggregation queries and so on.

In current design, we have no UPDATE operations. Currently, I'm experimenting with a highly normalized design (based on ideas promoted by Anchor modeling and/or 6NF). Such design would use JOINs and VIEWs extensively to make working with DB pleasant, and so needs a database to be able to do these efficiently.

As far as I can tell (based on problems like this), PostgreSQL doesn't seem to be a good fit to this design (with around 11 tables and a number of views) and seems to almost always perform worse than a less normalized design with one or two tables and no views. I was hoping that this problem in planning JOIN queries is my fault, but it doesn't seem so yet. With this problem, it seems that I should forget using VIEWS and use verbose queries with lots of repeated conditions, or forget using either PostgreSQL or this design.

#### Tables

The actual number of columns is a bit more, but they are not in any relation with other tables, and so should be irrelevant to this discussion:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('ids_seq'::regclass),
  total integer NOT NULL,
  price integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_t1 PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE t2
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  category smallint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_t2 PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY (id)
      REFERENCES t1 (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been **[moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34914/discussion-on-question-by-hedayat-postgresql-seems-to-create-inefficient-plans-i)**. Please use that chat room for further discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then it looks like an optimizer's blind spot and you should use the second query.

When there is a condition joining two tables `a` and `b`: `a.id = b.id` and an additional condition `a.id > @some_constant`, seems like the optimizer uses the "index condition" for where to start the index scan on `a (id)` index but it doesn't use it for the second index `b (id)`.

So, adding the (redundant) `b.id > @some_constant` allows it to produce a slightly more efficient plan, skipping a part of the `b (id)` index as well.

This could be posted as a suggestion for improvement (if it hasn't been already) to the Postgres hackers group.

---

After the edit, we know there is a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint from `t2` that `REFERENCES t1`. So the "natural" (equivalent) way to write the query would be:

```
SELECT
    -- whatever
FROM
    t2
  LEFT JOIN
    t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id > -9223372036513411363 ;
```

<sub><strike>Can you try this and tell us the execution plan it produces? There are some transformations that apply only to `LEFT` (outer) joins and not to inner joins.</strike></sub>
Unfortunately this doesn't produce any different plan either.

---

The OP has posted a question at the Postgres performance list, we can see the whole thread here: [PostgreSQL seems to create inefficient plans in simple conditional joins](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAKJS1f-0=25E0TnCOz2dy9aaJna9MtHC70Gv_NdpRxR4+iiJVA@mail.gmail.com#CAKJS1f-0=25E0TnCOz2dy9aaJna9MtHC70Gv_NdpRxR4+iiJVA@mail.gmail.com) and the reply by David Rowley, which confirms that this is a feature that although it has been considered, hasn't yet been implemented in the optimizer:

> **Yes, unfortunately you've done about the only thing that you can do,
>   and that's just include both conditions in the query.** Is there some
>   special reason why you can't just write the `t2.id > ...` condition in
>   the query too? or is the query generated dynamically by some software
>   that you have no control over?
>
> I'd personally quite like to see improvements in this area, and even
>   wrote a patch [1](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAKJS1f-0=25E0TnCOz2dy9aaJna9MtHC70Gv_NdpRxR4+iiJVA@mail.gmail.com#CAKJS1f-0=25E0TnCOz2dy9aaJna9MtHC70Gv_NdpRxR4+iiJVA@mail.gmail.com) which fixes this problem too. The problem I had when
>   proposing the fix for this was that I was unable to report details
>   about how many people are hit by this planner limitation. The patch I
>   proposed caused a very small impact on planning time for many queries,
>   and was thought by many not to apply in enough cases for it to be
>   worth slowing down queries which cannot possibly benefit. Of course I
>   agree with this, I've no interest in slowing down planning on queries,
>   but at the same time understand the annoying poor optimisation in this
>   area.
>
> Although please remember the patch I proposed was merely a first draft
>   proposal. Not for production use.